# ツアーの翻訳はどこで行われていますか？

Tags: サポート, 翻訳

どうも、[スタック・オーバーフローのツアー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour)に関して、 Transifex で翻訳されているテキスト（例: [例示質問のタイトル](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40286149?key=71037c43d50a114e7adfa7060dc1b372)）は無視されているようです。
おそらくツアーなどは、翻訳が必要ないコミュニティにおいてもカスタマイズの需要があるので、翻訳とは別のカスタマイズの方法が用意されており、それが優先されているのだと思います。

ツアーの修正はどこで行なわれていますか？
また、今後の翻訳は Transifex に集約するのが自然かと思いますが、これは可能でしょうか。

Comment: /help 以下のページは、手動メンテナンスだったはず。ツアーはどうだったか。。と思っている状態です。

Answer (score 4):

### Transifexで管理されている箇所

[`tour`のタグ](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40286111?tags=tour)をつけました。

### モデレーターが編集可能な箇所

これらは今のところメタで議論 → 更新というかたちになると思います。

- 冒頭の、ロゴ直下の段落
  [image]
- どの質問を例として表示するか
- よい質問の例、避けてほしい質問の例
  [image]

#### これらもTransifexに移行すべきか、について

スタックオーバーフロー以外の日本語Stack Exchangeサイトができた場合、これらはそれぞれのサイトごとにカスタマイズする箇所になるので、管理を分ける必要があります。また、「よい質問の例」などはサイトの方針に関わるので、メタで議論を通す必要がある仕組みは適しているように思います。

(その上で管理場所がTransifexであってもいいとは思います。でも翻訳にはタッチしないモデレーター陣であれば、Transifexをはさむことなく更新できた方がいいかな。)